# Фильтрация по свойствам

Tags: windows, powershell

В папке e:\ лежит много подпапок, ещё больше файлов с разными расширениями. Это неполный фрагмент фильтрации для примера, на деле он содержит больше указаний. Есть ли способ сделать запись короче?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path e:/ | where { $_.Name -notlike "driv*" -and $_.name -notlike "intel*" -and $_.Name -notlike "*.zip" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте оператор `-notmatch`, например:

```
 where { $_.Name -notmatch '^driv.*$|^.*.zip$|^intel.*$'}
```

так будет короче

Comment: Понятно, благодарю.